# Drop 'NaN' value in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

Is there any way to drop only 'nan' from a dataset not to remove the entire row or column which contains 'nan'? I have tried below code but the result was not the one that i wanted.

```
df = pd.read_csv('...csv')
df.stack()
```

Here is the part of csv

[image]

And here is after '.stack()'

[image]

The headers are mixed up with the actual data. I don't want to be mixed up!

Comment: What is the purpose of removing the NaN elements from your DataFrame? Is to compute some type of statistic (e.g. mean, standard deviation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.fillna('')
```

Which will fill na with an empty string ''. Or you can fill it whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

using [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with condition.

nan vlaue not equal itself.

---

and

you can drop column or row by using,

column: `del df.column_name`

row: `df.drop([row_index])`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))
df.iloc[1, 1] = np.nan 
print(df)

   0    1  2
0  0  1.0  2
1  3  NaN  5
2  6  7.0  8
```

You can drop just the middle cell but only if we `stack`

```
df.stack()

0  0    0.0
   1    1.0
   2    2.0
1  0    3.0
   2    5.0
2  0    6.0
   1    7.0
   2    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: doesn't work! I do have a header. When i am converting it to series i need to convert it back to dataframe and the problem is after conversion the header would be mixed with the other data which is not good!

Comment: It does work.  I demonstrated that it does.  Problem is, you didn't show us what you want it to look like.  In your mind, what does droping an na without dropping the row look like?

Comment: you can check initial code again to see what kind of problem i am talking about after applying stack()